# Xamarin Android - Custom Map Image Async

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm following this example:
[CustomMap](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/Map)

In the example the image is informed directly([On here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/CustomRenderers/Map/Droid/Resources/layout/XamarinMapInfoWindow.axml)):

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/xamarin" />
```

I changed it to:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/InfoWindowFoto"/>
```

and:

```
var infoFoto = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowFoto);              
if (infoFoto != null) GetImageBitmapFromUrl(infoFoto, customPin.local.Url_Imagem);
```

and:

```
private void GetImageBitmapFromUrl(ImageView img, string url)
    {
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
            if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                var bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                img.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
```

if the image is synchronous, it works with delay :(

If I change to asynchronous the image is not show:

```
var infoFoto = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowFoto);              
if (infoFoto != null) GetImageBitmapFromUrl(infoFoto, customPin.local.Url_Imagem);

private async void GetImageBitmapFromUrl(ImageView img, string url)
    {
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var imageBytes = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
            if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                var bitmap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArrayAsync(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                img.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to update a view to show an image after downloading it. I also tried Picasso with the same result:

```
var infoFoto = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowFoto);              
Picasso.Get().Load(customPin.local.Url_Imagem).Into(infoFoto);
```

Can you help me fix this please

EDIT:

also tried with FFImageloading:

if (infoFoto != null) ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(customPin.local.Url_Imagem).Into(infoFoto);

When I click on the pin the image does not appear. But if I click off the pin and the view closes, and I click on the pin again for the view to open the image appears quickly!

I need to know if it is possible to update the view inside the map after the image is downloaded...

My sample: [Sample Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jc48xrDPjQl7r9yVZXFCEK63MyitJX6R/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried to SetImageBitmap in mainthread,like      `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=> {img.SetImageBitmap(bitmap); });`

Comment: Hi Leo thanks. Same result reported :(

Comment: Make a breakpoint ,see if you get the bitmap  when request with the webclient.

Comment: Hi, yes, i get the bitmap, it really just doesn't update the view after

Comment: I mistook it for a Forms project.Have you tried  `RunOnUiThread(() => {img.SetImageBitmap(bitmap); });`

Comment: Hi! thanks for the tip, it also didn't work :(

Comment: added a try on the question using FFimageloading

Comment: Ok,Does  FFimageloading work ?

Comment: Hello, The first time you click on the pin, the empty view opens. I have to click on the pin to close the view and click on the pin again for it to appear. The first time he clicks, he needs to download the image, but does not show the image at the end of the download. When I click it a second time, because the image is already in the cache, it appears. Unfortunately I still haven't found a solution for the image to appear after the download is finished.

Comment: Try to get the bitmap by `MemoryStream` like  `using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes)){Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(ms);}`

Comment: Hi, not found. I need to know if it is possible to update the view inside the map after the image is downloaded

Comment: It's weird,the codes  look correct.

Comment: You could share a simple demo If possible.

Comment: Yes I can! Thanks. I edited the question and added it at the end

Comment: ok,i will test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is rendered as an image (using `View.draw(Canvas)`) at the time it is returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not be reflected by the info window on the map.

To update the info window later (for example, after an image has loaded), call `showInfoWindow()`.

You could try the below codes:

```
private Bitmap bitmap;
public  Android.Views.View GetInfoContents(Marker marker)
    {
        var inflater = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as Android.Views.LayoutInflater;
        if (inflater != null)
        {
            Android.Views.View view;


            var customPin = GetCustomPin(marker);
            if (customPin == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Local não localizado");
            }

            if (customPin.local.Name.Equals("Xamarin"))
            {
                view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.XamarinMapInfoWindow, null);
            }
            else
            {
                view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MapInfoWindow, null);
            }

            var infoTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowTitle);
            if (infoTitle != null) infoTitle.Text = marker.Title;
            var infoSubtitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowSubtitle);
            if (infoSubtitle != null) infoSubtitle.Text = marker.Snippet;
            var infoNote = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoNote);
            if(infoNote != null) infoNote.Text = customPin.local.Note;
            var infoFoto = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowFoto);
            if (infoFoto != null && bitmap == null)
            {
                GetImageBitmapFromUrlAsync(infoFoto, customPin.local.Url_Imagem, marker);
            }
            else
            {
                infoFoto.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            return view;
        }
        return null;
    }
  

private async void GetImageBitmapFromUrlAsync(ImageView img, string url, Marker marker)
    {
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var imageBytes = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
            if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                bitmap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArrayAsync(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                marker.ShowInfoWindow();
            }
        }
        
    }
```

if your image_urls are not the same,you could use `Dictionary` to store the bitmap,use the url as the key,the bitmap as the value.

Comment: I sincerely thank you for your help! You, in addition to several tips, tested my project and gave me the solution. Thank you very much.